# Finding all Points inside a given radius

Tags: c#, .net

Input: Given a specific co-ordinate (latitude and longitude) and distance, Output: Displaying all the points inside that distance (km)

How can I get all the points inside the **radius** I've commented out the code I had initially started, was trying to return minimum distance to every cafe but wasn't sure how to go about it.

```
    public async Task<PaginationResponse> GetSearchVenue(int? MaxDistance, double? latitude, double? longitude, int pageNumber, int pageCount, bool active)

       {
            var cafe = _context.Restaurant.Where(w => w.IsDeleted != active);
            Point currentLocation = null;
            if (latitude.HasValue && longitude.HasValue)
            {
                currentLocation = new Point(latitude.Value, longitude.Value)
                {
                    SRID = 4326
                };
                cafe = cafe.Where(w => w.Latitude.HasValue && w.Longitude.HasValue);
            }

            //calculate maxdistance 
            var distanceInKm = currentLocation.Distance(new Point(latitude.Value, longitude.Value)) / 1000;

            //if its less than the maxdistance then display all the restaurants in that radius 
            //if(distanceInKm < MaxDistance)
            //{
            //    cafe = cafe.Where(w => w.);
            //}

           //gets the closest distance to current location 
           Distance = currentLocation != null ? currentLocation.Distance(new Point(s.Latitude.Value, s.Longitude.Value)) : 0

      }
```

Comment: What distance are you trying to calculate with the first `currentLocation.Distance()`? It seems this will always be zero. Also: latitude and longitude are both nullables. what are you suppose to do when they are null?

Comment: _all points_ ?? From a list of points or all points with integer coordinates or what?

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel if it's null then it will return a 0. what I was trying to calculate was a point which I would set as the maximum distance but wasn't sure how to go ahead with it

Comment: @TaW pretty much theres a list of cafes -> and i want to return all cafes within a 10 km radius of my current location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Input: Given a specific co-ordinate (latitude and longitude) and distance, Output: Displaying all the points inside that distance (km)

We do not have all the context for the method and its parameters, but I assuming the method doesn't receive null values and the `cafe` is a IEnumerable of latitudes and longitudes, the following code should work.

```
void SearchNearby (double max_distance, double latitude, double longitude) {
    return cafe.Where((lat, lon) => {
        return CalcDistance(lat,lon, latitude, longitude) <= max_distance;
    });
}
```

Also assuming of course that `max_distance` is in km.
[Here is a site that shows different ways of calculating the distance between two coordenates.](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

For small distances you can even use the formula to calculate the distance between two points in a plane.

Comment: I don't have a method called CalcDistance?

Comment: @JamesMcCoy That is fine. There is more than one way to do the calculation. Check this site: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. Read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already got distance calculation, put it in linq such like this

```
if (distanceInKm < MaxDistance)
{
    var distanceInMeter = distanceInKm * 1000;
    cafe = cafe.Where(w => currentLocation.Distance(new Point(w.lat, w.lng)) <= distanceInMeter);
}
```